# How to connect keyboard and mouse on AndroidTV so that it works with Cast (Screen Mirroring) on my phone

Tags: android-tv, screencast

Recently, I have been looking for ways to cast my phone screen to AndroidTV. I found a way with Android's built-in thing for screen casting and all worked well.

Now, since I'm not a fan of the idea of looking for Bluetooth keyboard and mouse, I am interested to know if it's possible to attach a mouse and a keyboard to the AndroidTV (where the screen is being casted from the phone) and for it to work on my phone.

Cause the AndroidTV has USB ports, I want my phone screen shown on the TV but it doesn't make much sense if I have to look at my phone for everything.

Comment: Do you use the Chrome cast functionality which simply forwards the playlist to the cast target or do you simply cast the visible screen of your phone?

Comment: I just use Cast and this thing called Screen Mirroring on my AndroidTV. So far, it's making my screen visible on TV, but I have no options to use a mouse attached to the USB port of my TV or anything like that. Surprisingly though, when I play sound on my phone, it is heard with the TV's speakers

Comment: As the name implies casting was developed to "redirect" videos from the small smartphone screen to the TV. Therefore display and sound to the TV works. The opposite direction is not possible, I assume because of security problems, because otherwise you would never know if it is safe to connect to a TV or not. If you want to fully remote control a phone then you have to use appropriate remote control software like like TeamViewer.